# XML to Java Object

Tags: java, xml, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java converting XML to Java objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276149/java-converting-xml-to-java-objects)

Hi,

Can someone please suggest the best and different ways of converting a XML file to an Java object?

Thanks & Regards,
Ravi.

Comment: duplicate of question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276149/java-converting-xml-to-java-objects/3276551#3276551

Comment: Please search the relevant question before posting it.

Comment: Tushar, its not the same. What I am looking for is that if I only have the XML file, no object, then what can I use which can create the java Class for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can user available frameworks like [Castor](http://www.castor.org/) or [Xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)

I would recommend Xstream considering the simplicity of use. This [2 minute tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) of Xstream will help you to get started quickly.

Comment: If I am not wrong, Castor need the XML Schema if you were to create the java object, not sure same for Sstream. Actually, what I am looking for is that if I only have the XML file, no object, then what can I use which can create the java Class for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of xml-to-java-frameworks around. In the past I've worked a lot with [jibx](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/).