# Convert XML to Java Object

Tags: java, xml, converters, calculator

I was just wondering if someone can show me a quick way of converting an XML file to Java object from this sample:

```
- <VM-DataCalculator>
- <device name="Blackberry" fname="BlackBerry">
- <dataCategory>
  <name>email</name> 
  <datarate>0.002</datarate> 
  <max>300</max> 
  <percent>12</percent> 
  <timeunit>month</timeunit> 
  </dataCategory>
- <dataCategory>
  <name>emailAttachment</name> 
  <datarate>0.2</datarate> 
  <max>100</max> 
  <percent>10</percent> 
  <timeunit>month</timeunit> 
  </dataCategory>
```

Full file is available here: http://www.virginmobile.ca/en/catalogue/VMDataCalculator.xml

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean DOM-model of XML?

Comment: Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28394/adx_j_parser.htm

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276149/converting-xml-to-java-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard solution, using nothing but the Java framework would be to use [JAXP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/index.html). There are [numerous other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D%20%5Bxml%5D%20parse).

JAXP is a bit bloated, to parse some XML into DOM you'd have to do the following:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbfactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder domparser = dbfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = domparser.parse("http://www.virginmobile.ca/en/catalogue/VMDataCalculator.xml");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need JAXB. This is basically how it works, you create your model classes

```
@XmlRootElement(name="VM-DataCalculator")
class VMDataCalculator {
    @XmlElement(name = "device")
    List<Device> devices;
}

@XmlRootElement
class Device {
    @XmlElement(name = "dataCategory")
    List<DataCategory> dataCategories;
}

@XmlRootElement
class DataCategory {
    @XmlElement
    String name;
          ....
}
```

and unmarshal your xml

```
 VMDataCalculator c = JAXB.unmarshal(new File("1.xml"), VMDataCalculator.class);
```

more details here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/index.html