# Parse Xml to Java using SimpleXml

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jaxb, simple-framework

How to parse this with simpleXml or JAXB (I want to convert it to a java object) :

```
<properties xmlns:im="http://itunes.apple.com/rss">
   <id im:id="one">id1</id>
   <name>name1</name>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map it with the following classes using a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation.

**Properties**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Properties {

    private Id id;
    private String name;
```

}

**Id**

Since the attribute is namespace qualified you need to include this in the `@XmlAttribute` annotation.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Id {

    @XmlAttribute(namespace="http://itunes.apple.com/rss")
    private String id;

    @XmlValue
    private String value;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html

Answer (score 0):

Just read

- [how to parse xml to java object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364547/how-to-parse-xml-to-java-object)

Or

- [Converting XML to Java objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276149/converting-xml-to-java-objects)

Both have more than enough information.  And so do a lot of other SO questions...

Comment: It works fine without this the im: in  im:id="one" but when I add it, it generate an exception. Please help, I try many solutions before asking.

Comment: Cool, glad to hear that!  Accept the answer if it helped (I believe you'll get a bronze badge if you do ;) )

Comment: My problem is with this : im:id="one", I can't found how to parse it, please give me a working sample code. Here is the documentation : http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#namesoace